# Request token from Flutter

Tags: flutter

[How to fix this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhp6N.png)
How to fix this? I want to make a request from a flutter to a postman to get a token.

Comment: Do not post images of text

Answer (score 0):

First you should convert your **URI** from string,

```
Uri finalUrl = Uri.parse(url.toString);
```

after pass the **finalUrl** to your post method

```
final response = await http.post(finalUrl, body: request_param);
```